# Should logic go into trigger actions or in the entry?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I was wondering if it is better to put long execution logic in triggers or in states.

My concern is that if I put a complex, long logic within the triggers, then my state machine would stay too much time in a transitioning phase, and the information about the current state is no more meaningful.

Would the entry of each state the correct place to put long running logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put logic in a state directly but in a state entry or exit event. So no matter where you place it is runs as part of a state transition. Now as to what is the correct place, that completely depends on the logic. Simply stated, put it where it is appropriate :-)